# SPNavigation.Children always returns 0

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss

I am working with SP2010 foundation but I dont think much has changed since WSS3.

I am trying to create a custom menu for a foundation project this is what I have so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:3002/"))
        {
            SPNavigation nav =site.RootWeb.Navigation;

            //gets the correct order of top level menu items
            SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = nav.TopNavigationBar;

            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPNavigationNode toplinkbar = web.Navigation.GetNodeById(1002);
                if (toplinkbar != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPNavigationNode node in toplinkbar.Children)
                        PrintNode(node);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue....");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintNode(SPNavigationNode node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Title);
        foreach (SPNavigationNode item in node.Children)
            PrintNode(item);
    }
```

So the 1st part toplinkbar.Children is working correctly however the foreach loop in PrintNode node.Children is always returning 0 when I know there child sites within the site.

Am I meant to be getting the subsites using SPSiteMapProvider?

Any help would be great as this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the NavigationNodeCollection attached to the TopNavigation. That is cannonical source of TopNav information.

When you load that 'Root' node in that manner it's loaded in a disconnected manner.
I have an old blog post that might help somewhat. http://gavinb.net/2008/05/27/sharepoint-navigation-elements-how-to-code-with-them